# Laravel Breeze - Localization when using Vue stack

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm starting a new project in Laravel, installed Laravel Breeze for handling user authentication, but I'm facing a problem, when I try to translate the application to spanish using folder lang/es.json, It doesn't work, It's still showing in english and the locale setting in config/app.php is configured to 'es'.

I've been doing some tests and realized that when I installed laravel Breeze, I chose Vue stack, this modified the routes in routes/web.php file and now routes use Inertia to render the views, I rewrote one of those routes to its default laravel configuration and the translation in that view are working fine, so the question is, what should I do for translating those views rendered with Inertia? this is how my web.php file looks.

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Comment: Can you update the code. the current web.php (with inerja) and the previous web.php where the translation was implemented.

Comment: I recently had the same issue with Laravel Inertia VueJS with localization. If you still have the same issue and uses the same stack that I do, please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768650/localization-for-laravel-inertia-vuejs

Comment: Did you solve this? I want to translate the breeze Reset password email text, don't know where to change this.