# Localization for Laravel Inertia VueJs

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-10, laravel-localization

I am trying to set up [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) on my Laravel [Inerita](https://inertiajs.com/how-it-works) ([Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js)). I know about `https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization`, but this does not support Inertia (at least I was not successful with running this on my Vue.js file) `{{ __("text") }}` does not work in inertia error: `TypeError: _ctx.__ is not a function`.

Anyway, I am using a different localization package called `laravel-vue-i18n`.

I am successful in using this on Vue.js, but I am having problems when setting the locale based on URL. How do I set my routes/middleware to use a nullable locale (*en* as default)?

#### File *web.php*

```
// Can be nullable locale?
Route::middleware(['setLocale'])->prefix('{locale?}')->group(function () {
  Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
  Route::resource('comments', CommentController::class);

});
```

#### File *SetLocaleMiddleware.php*

```
class SetLocaleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $locale = 'en')
    {
        \Log::info($locale); // Always logs as 'en' even if I add 'ja' in the URL
        \Log::info($request->route('locale')); // Locale or whatever is the text after localhost/ for some reason

        if (!in_array($locale, ['en', 'ja'])) {
            abort(400);
        }

        App::setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### File *app/Kernel.php*

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'setLocale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocaleMiddleware::class,
];
```

Expected results:

```
// Set application language to Japanese
http://localhost/ja
http://localhost/ja/posts
http://localhost/ja/comments

// Set application language to English as default
http://localhost
http://localhost/posts
http://localhost/comments
```

Note: it does not have to be middleware.

Comment: your middleware isn't taking a paramater ... `locale` is a route parameter, not a parmeter to a middleware ... this would be a middleware parameter: `setLocale:parameter` but you don't have one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution that worked for me, though I am not able to use the `\ja` in the url route, but instead use laravel's `Session` facade and update the locale in vue on the fly using `createApp`

1. `npm install laravel-vue-i18n`
2. publish the lang files: `php artisan lang:publish`
3. copy the en directory and change to your desired new locale (mine was ja)
4. optional (create a post.php or any other php file inside the directory)

```
app
  lang
    en
      auth.php
      pagination.php
      password.php
      post.php
      validation.php
    ja
      auth.php
      pagination.php
      password.php
      post.php
      validation.php
```

5. Add `i18nVue` from `laravel-vue-i18n` in app.ts file

**File app.ts**

```
// Format may be different for app.js (remove ':string') inside async
import { createApp, h, DefineComponent } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { i18nVue } from "laravel-vue-i18n";

createInertiaApp({
    ...
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            ...
            .use(i18nVue, {
                fallbackLang: "en",
                resolve: async (lang: string) => {
                    const langs: any = import.meta.glob("../../lang/*.json");
                    return await langs[`../../lang/${lang}.json`]();
                },
            })
            ...
    },
});
```

6. add `i18n` in vite.config.js

**vite.config.js**

```
import i18n from "laravel-vue-i18n/vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        ...
        i18n(),
    ],
});
```

7. add `lang/php_*.json` in .gitignore
8. add a `Route::group` in your web.php. Also include the controller@method to update the locale.

**File web.php**

```
Route::post('/locale', [SetLocaleController::class, 'locale'])->name('locale');

Route::middleware(['setLocale'])->group(function () {
  Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
  Route::resource('comments', CommentController::class);
});
```

9. create new middleware `php artisan make:middleware SetLocaleMiddleware`

**File SetLocaleMiddleware.php**

```
class SetLocaleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // get locale from session or get default value 'en'
        $locale = Session::get('locale', 'en');
        App::setLocale($locale);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

10. create new controller `php artisan make:controller SetLocaleController`

**File SetLocaleController.php**

```
class SetLocaleController extends Controller
{
    public function locale(Request $request)
    {
        // set locale to session
        Session::put('locale', $request->get('locale'));
        $data = ['locale' => $request->get('locale')];
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

11. Update `HandleInertiaRequests` to return `locale` as props

**File HandleInertiaRequests.php**

```
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    ...
    public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            ...parent::share($request),
            ...
            'locale' => Session::get('locale', 'en'),
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

12. In your VueJS File, there are multiple ways to toggle locale select, radio, etc. Use what you want and maybe use below how to switch the locale:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { i18nVue } from "laravel-vue-i18n";
import axios from "axios";

const app = createApp({});

// the method to update the locale. remote ':string` if in not using typescript.
const toggleLocale = async (locale: string) => {
    await axios
        .post(route("locale"), { locale: locale })
        .then((response) => {
            app.use(i18nVue, {
                lang: response.data.props.locale,
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

Bonus, if you are experiencing error 419 (missing csrf token), do the following in your axios (preferably in app.ts/js)

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
```

### **How to use**

**lang/en/post.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'add, :title' => 'Add :title',
];
```

**lang/ja/post.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'add, :title' => ':titleを追加',
];
```

**any vuejs files**

```
<template>
    ...
    {{ trans("post.add, :title", { title: props.title,}) }}
    <!-- 'post' is from post.php while add is the key -->
    <!-- you can also add parameters here too. -->
    ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { trans } from "laravel-vue-i18n";
</script>
```

Routes stays as

```
// Set application language to English as default
http://localhost
http://localhost/posts
http://localhost/comments
```